# How can i fix the 'unexpected token {' error NodeJS keeps throwing at me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I am trying to learn data structures with JavaScript, I have babel set in VSCode, I am trying to use the import/export syntax for my classes but whenever I try to run my code using node I keep getting:

> "(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {
>   defaultToString } from './toString' SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

I have tried switching up export/export default to the require syntax but when I tried that I got an error which said that my class is not a constructor

This is my code :

```
export function defaultToString (item) {
    if (item === null) {
        return 'NULL';
    }else if (item === undefined) {
        return 'UNDEFINED';
    }else if (typeof item === 'string' || item instanceof String) {
        return `${item}`;
    }
    return item.toString();
}

export class ValuePair {
    constructor (key, value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    toString () {
        return `[#${this.key}: ${this.value}]`
    }
}

import { defaultToString } from './toString'
import { ValuePair } from './ValuePair'

class HashTable {
    constructor(toStrFn = defaultToString) {
        this.toStrFn = toStrFn;
        this.table = {};
    }
}
```

Comment: What target environment are you using for babel?

Comment: If that is your exact code, you are missing a closing } at the very end for your HashTable class.

Comment: Your node version doesn't seem to support `import`/`export` natively yet. Looks like your babel setup doesn't convert imports/exports. This might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class HashTable is missing closing braces like

```
class HashTable {
    constructor(toStrFn = defaultToString) {
        this.toStrFn = toStrFn;
        this.table = {};
    }
}
```

If you are using node environment

you should be importing by using required as below

```
const defaultToString =  required('./defaultToString')
```

and export by using module.export as below

```
module.export = { defaultString }
```

Comment: `s/required/require/`

Answer (score 0):

A single } at the end should fix it.

Comment: I think comment would be enough ;-)